# Different result of XML parser in different environment, WHY?

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php
$xml = <<< AAA
<test>c đưa lên 1 -&gt; 10 k</test>
AAA;
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
print_r($vals);
```

I can get differnt result  why?
In my PC the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => TEST
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 1
            [value] => c đưa lên 1 -> 10 k
        )

)
```

In the procuction environment, the resut is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => TEST
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 1
            [value] => c đưa lên 1 - 10 k
        )

)
```

The *>* is disappear.
Why?

Comment: Bug of libxml2 when using PHP <= 5.2.6 with libxml2 >= 2.6.32. 
PHP 5.2.7 or higher works with the new behaviour of libxml2 ( see: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996 ). Simply upgrading PHP corrects the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, when you switch environments, you will see some differences related to text encoding and other internationlization-related gotchas. So you can try explicitly setting an encoding in the [xml_parser_create](http://php.net/xml_parser_create) function.

Another thing to consider is PHP versions. Run a `phpinfo()` from both environments and check the versions there. It may be that the PHP version production is using is coded to ignore HTML entities (&gt;) ... just a guess.

**EDIT:**
According to this [bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996), this behavior of ignoring HTML entities can be cause by libxml2. Try updating libxml2 on the production server to the latest version.

Comment: Can not see any difference of phpinfo. The encoding of both are utf8.

Comment: Check the bug report in my edit. If the php versions are the same, then the libxml2 difference would make sense.

Comment: Both of the libxml2 Version is 2.6.32

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an encoding problem.